# Jest.js tests don't pass when expected/received values are objects

Tags: unit-testing, redux, javascript-objects, jestjs

I'm testing this reducer:

```js
const todo = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TODO':
      return {
        id: action.id,
        text: action.text,
        completed: false
      }
    case 'TOGGLE_TODO':
      if(state.id !== action.id) {
        return state;
      }
      return {...state, completed: !state.completed};

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const todos = (state = [], action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TODO':
      return [
        ...state,
        todo(undefined, action)
      ]
    case 'TOGGLE_TODO':
      return state.map(item => todo(item, action));
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default todos;
```

With this test:

```js
import todos from './todos';

test('creates a new todo', () => {
  const stateBefore = [];
  const action = {
    type: 'ADD_TODO',
    id: 0,
    text: 'test'
  };
  const stateAfter = [{
    id: 0,
    text: 'test',
    completed: false
  }];

  expect( JSON.stringify( todos(stateBefore, action) ) ).toBe( JSON.stringify(stateAfter) );
});
```

The problem is that my tests fail with a `Compared values have no visual difference` remark if I remove the `JSON.stringify()` calls - I get that comparing an object to an object poses some problems because of reference, but do I have to use `JSON.stringify()` or loop through the object keys to compare them each time?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I'm answering my own question.

The `.toBe` method tests for exact (`===`) equality. In order to compare objects, you have to use the `.toEqual` method which does recursive checks of every object key / array index, depending on your data type.

In conclusion, you don't have to use `JSON.stringify()` and Jest goes through object keys for you, you just have to use the right equality testing method.

Source: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/using-matchers.html#content

Comment: Also in case anything else is just starting to test with React/Jest/Enzyme... I was getting the same error even after stringifying everything! 
I had forgot to mock up 'keys' for my unique list item!!

 Expected value to equal:
      "{\"type\":\"li\",\"key\":null,\"ref\":null,\"props\":{\"children\":\"eggs\"},\"_owner\":null,\"_store\":{}}"
    Received:
      "{\"type\":\"li\",\"key\":\"0\",\"ref\":null,\"props\":{\"children\":\"eggs\"},\"_owner\":null,\"_store\":{}}"

Only after stringifying like the official answer was I able to find out where I went wrong! ty!