# How to assert the value of the preselected value from a dropdown using Playwright? Typescript

Tags: typescript, dropdown, assertion, playwright

How to assert the value of the preselected value from a dropdown using Playwright? Typescript

I am using the below code to assert the preselected value of a dropdown.

```
const dropdownValue = await this.page.$eval<string, HTMLSelectElement>("#recommendations_recommendation", ele => ele.value);
    expect(dropdownValue).toBe("Approve");
```

I am getting the below error in the console:-

```
Error: expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: "Approve"
    Received: ""
```

The webelement locator is correct i.e. the CSS path. Not sure why it is throwing me error. Can anyone please help me here to get the value of the dropdown?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hey, Please refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42330216/8835695
Also, not much context is given so the above answer seems perfect

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```js
const locator = page.locator('#recommendations_recommendation');
await expect(locator).toHaveValue('Approve');
```

You can try asserting the inner text:

```js
const locator = page.locator('#recommendations_recommendation');
await expect(locator).toHaveText('Approve');
```

Comment: Hey Alapan, with the above, I am getting the below error:-                                                             Error: expect(received).toHaveValue(expected)

    Expected string: "Approve"
    Received string: ""
    Call log:
      - expect.toHaveValue with timeout 5000ms
      - waiting for selector "#recommendations_recommendation"
      -   selector resolved to <input value="" type="search" role="combobox" autocompl…/>
      -   unexpected value ""

Comment: Her is the complete HTML for that element:-                                              <input id="recommendations_recommendation" autocomplete="off" type="search" class="ant-select-selection-search-input" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-owns="recommendations_recommendation_list" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="recommendations_recommendation_list" aria-activedescendant="recommendations_recommendation_list_0" value="" aria-expanded="false">

Comment: Getting this now :-      Error: expect(received).toHaveText(expected)

    Expected string: "Approve"
    Received string: ""
    Call log:
      - expect.toHaveText with timeout 5000ms
      - waiting for selector "#recommendations_recommendation"
      -   selector resolved to <input value="" type="search" role="combobox" autocompl…/>
      -   unexpected value ""